# Setting Order Status with Payment Gateway

Tags: magento2.3, payment-gateway, order-status

I'm a Magento beginner. I'm trying to create a **custom offline payment gateway**, that will function like a **check/money** order type gateway. I've got something rough up and working by following this tutorial:

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/2361-2/

As I understand it, this gateway should be putting orders into 'pending_payment' status upon placement. Is see this line in Pendingpayment.php:

```
class Pendingpayment extends Status
{
/**
* @var string[]
*/
protected $_stateStatuses = [Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT];
}
```

But when orders are placed with this gateway, they are in the 'processing' status. If I pull the order using the API (mysite/rest/V1/orders/{id}), I see both a state and status of 'processing'.

How can I get this gateway to put orders in 'payment_pending' status until further action?

Comment: have you made it work? and are you sure this is a magento 2.3 version?

Comment: No, not working. I left another comment below. It says 2.3 in the Admin panel.

Comment: tried to follow the instructions from the link but it seems it is for magento 1

Comment: Why do you say that? That page says 2.3. It also mostly works with my 2.3 installation, except for this order status issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting static pending status:

```
class Pendingpayment extends Status
{
/**
* @var string[]
*/
protected $_stateStatuses = 'pending';
}
```

And check if it changes the status

Comment: I made this change, and ran all my bin/magento commands, setup:upgrade, cache:clean etc.. placed a new order, and it still puts it into processing.

Comment: it seems to me that the issue is not with the current code. have you tried choosing another payment method? does it give the same status?

Comment: because basically, new order should have a state of new and status of pending.

Comment: maybe you have a plugin or an observer from a custom or third-party extension that changes the state and status upon order checkout

Comment: I had one other custom plugin I had built active, for a payment gateway. I disabled this and removed. I don't think I have any other 3rd party plugins. This is a brand new barebones Magento installation. I tried placing an order using the built-in Check/Money Order option, and that puts the order into 'pending' status.